# Which method should change the field, when calling a hierarcy of private methods?

Tags: java, methods, field, conventions

When a class' public method needs to call a private method that results in a field being changed, which method should change the field? Is there any common convention for this? Is one approach preferable over the other?

Consider these two code snippets:

```
public class boolHolder {
    private boolean theBool = false;

    public void doYourThing() {
        // Do a lot of other stuff
        setBool();
    }

    private void setBool() {
        // Do a lot of other stuff, justifying a private method for this
        this.theBool = true;
    }
}
```

**VS**

```
public class boolHolder {
    private boolean theBool = false;

    public void doYourThing() {
        // Do a lot of other stuff
        theBool = setBool();
    }

    private boolean setBool() {
        // Do a lot of other stuff, justifying a private method for this
        return true;
    }
}
```

These two snipped of course being a very simple case, but I'm sure I'm not the only one ending up with public methods calling a huge tree of private methods. Should the field be set at the end of the branch, or should a value be passed back?

Comment: in general it is better to use public setters and keep fields private, thus setting the field would be possible from any where the class accessible. 
your doYourThing() method looks to me that it is not actually a setter; it could also contain other logic. feels like not a good place to perform the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it makes more sense that only a single place would set the value of the field, and it should be the last method being called. It makes the code easier to understand. Your first snippet looks much more readable to me.

Here's another snippet which, in my opinion, supports this convention :

Lets say we have an int member with two setters - one accepts an int and the other accepts a String representation of that int (which is used, for example, if we de-serialize an instance from an XML String).

```
int value;

public void setIntField (String value) 
  throws SomeException
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new SomeException();
    try {
        int val = Integer.parseInt (value);
        setIntField (val);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}

public void setIntField (int value)
    throws SomeException ()
{
    if (value < MIN_ALLOWED || value > MAX_ALLOWED)
        throw new SomeException ();
    this.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from renaming `theBool` and `setBool` to something more understandable (which I'm going to assume you did eitherway in the real application), I'd go with the first one. Methods with the word `set` are expected to be setters and not many people will expect a return value.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change much, but you can try to use a better naming for your methods: i don't like that you name your second method setBool().

If you write "Do a lot of other stuff, justifying a private method for this" you can try to associate a *verb* to that stuff you do.
Say you update an account status and upon completion want to signal with the boolean the status, well use something like what you did but call it in a meaningful way, e.g. updateAccount() and either return a true if the update went fine or set it inside:

```
public class boolHolder {
    private boolean accountUpdated = false;

    public void doYourThing() {
       // Do a lot of preliminary stuff
       updateAccount();
    }

   private void updateAccount() {
       // try to update account
       // if update went fine
       this.accountUpdated = true;
   }
}
```

or

```
public class boolHolder {
    private boolean accountUpdated = false;

    public void doYourThing() {
       // Do a lot of preliminary stuff
       this.accountUpdated = updateAccount();
    }

   private boolean updateAccount() {
       // try to update account
       // if error happens, rollback change and set
       return false;
       // else (update went fine)
       return true;
   }
}
```

are both perfectly fine, but make your method tell what they do, since updating the bool is not the main action since you "Do a lot of other stuff, justifying a private method for this".

The value setting inside is more compact if you use a default to false as you did, but the other is more explicit in what it does. So I tend to prefer that: returning a result for you operation.